# React Native - Fetching array using <Text>

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a call from my api and display my **data/array** using a <**Text**>, but my output is **blank**.

I also tried this "this.setState({ menu_name: json[0].ordName })", **BUT** it would just fetch a single data. What I'm targeting is to fetch an array.

Here is my code

settlement.js

```
constructor(props){
super(props)
    this.state = {
        ....
        menu_name: []
        tbl: this.props.navigation.state.params.tbl,
    };
}
fetchOrdName = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://192.168.254.100:3308/OrdName/ordName/" + this.state.tbl )
    const json = await response.json()
    this.setState({ menu_name: json })
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchOrdName();
    .....
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
             .....
                    <View>
                        <Text>Name: { this.state.menu_name.ordName }</Text>
                        ....
                    </View>
            />
        <View/>
)}
```

My backend:

OrdName.js (models)

```
var Task = {
    OrdName:function(id,callback) {
        return db.query("SELECT menu_name AS ordName FROM orders where tbl_id=?",[id],callback);
    },
}
```

OrdName.js (routes)

```
var Task = require('../models/OrdName');

router.get('/ordName/:id?', (req, res, next) => {
    Task.OrdName(req.params.id,function(err,rows){
        if(err)
        {
            res.json(err);
        }
        else{
            res.json(rows);
        }
    });
});
```

Screenshots:

Sending the data to api

[image: Sending]

Receiving data from api

[image: Receiving]

My output in Postman:

[image: Postman]

This Names should be displayed.

Two data from api.

[image]

Comment: From the postman screenshot; the names are in an array form but the app screenshot only shows 1 slot for names. Are they suppose to be join into 1 string like "Fish (Fish Fillet) / Redhorse (500ml)"?

Comment: No sir, wait. I'll update some screenshot

Comment: I see, so there are more than 1items. In that case you should actually put the names into the list of the menu objects instead of using them directly like that. The reason why the names is not showing is probably due this.state.menu_name is an array of objects and Text cannot show that.

Comment: I'm aware about the fact that it would be hard for Text to hold arrays, sir. But as you can see in my code, my Text is inside a View which is already inside a Flatlist. So I'm not sure on how I will execute your suggestion which would be a List inside a List. (I'm not 100% sure if this is what your pointing at, sir)

Comment: Try checking my answer, see if that helps. The idea is that you want to use only one array.

Comment: I'll try to  analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch("http://192.168.254.100:3308/OrdName/ordName/" + this.state.tbl )
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseData) => {
    this.setState({ menu_name: responseData })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sir. But it still didn't working. the "Name: " is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

U have to try id with parseInt for typecasting.

```
let id =parseInt(this.state.tbl);

fetch(`http://192.168.254.100:3308/OrdName/ordName/${id}`)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseData) => {
    this.setState({ menu_name: responseData })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sir. But it still not displaying the name that I sent to my api.

Comment: u have to pass id in params so how can u get a name. u will t try console ur request and check which parameter u have to get in a request.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, your fetched data `menu_name` is an array. Then you should be accessing its content like `<Text>Name: { this.state.menu_name[ 0 ].ordName }</Text>` or loop throught it like:

```
{    
     this.state.menu_name.map( ( menu ) => {
         return ( <Text>{menu.ordName}</Text> )
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Text cannot show array of objects thus it shows empty. Try putting the name into the array of the ordered items as well for example (I assume this.state.ordered_item is the array that contains all the ordered info):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    menu_name: [],
    ordered_item: [{name: '', price:110, discount: 0, quantity: 1}, {name: '', price:105, discount: 0, quantity: 1}],
  };
}

fetchOrdName = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://192.168.254.100:3308/OrdName/ordName/" + this.state.tbl )
    const json = await response.json()
    for (let i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
      this.state.ordered_item[i].name = json[i].ordName;
    }
    this.setState(this.state);
}
```

then in when rendering, rather than using 2 different array, just use one:

```
<FlatList data={this.state.ordered_item}
          renderItem={(item)=>{
            <View>
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
              {the rest of the rendering codes}
            </View>
          }} />
```